# jQuery.steps--how to clear a wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I have created a form with 5 tabs in jquery-steps. 
How to clear the form, once a i close the form and again reopen i get all fields are filled with the values.
I want to reset the form without page refresh..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> $("form input").val("");

Something like that, with jQuery.